# How to use Swift Playgrounds-style code input keyboard/text field in normal text view?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, keyboard, swift-playground

I'm making an iPad app that lets me write swift code into a text box and save it to a document. It doesn't do any compilation or any complicated stuff like that, so I'm just looking for a way to format the code correctly in the text box (ex: code autocomplete, autoindent if possible, and maybe syntax highlighting). In short, I'd like my app's text field and keyboard to look similar to those of Swift Playgrounds.

If Apple's provided the code (or a built-in keyboard option that can do even some of this), I'd appreciate a link to it. Otherwise, how would I go about building a custom keyboard and text field (or at least disable the features like autocomplete that would get in the way)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to do what you describe is to build a Swift Playgrounds app that presents a code editor window. Apple does provide documentation on creating third party iPad Swift playgrounds. I suggest looking it up on Apple's site.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. Thanks anyway.